# How to change velocity & acceleration in MotionPlanRequest topic

Tags: moveit

[image: Rosanswers logo]

With the newest version of MoveIt! (Indigo 0.7.6), we can nicely scale the velocity and acceleration of trajectory on MoveIt! RViz plugin. Looking at the [Time Parameterization tutorial](http://docs.ros.org/api/moveit_tutorials/html/doc/time_parameterization_tutorial.html) changing them programmatically during runtime seems also possible by changing `MotionPlanRequest.msg`, but how exactly can we do so?

Now I'm trying to see using NEXTAGE but I don't see that type of topic being published while MoveIt! is running.

[Related question](http://answers.ros.org/question/250190/speed-up-rvizmoveit/) by @robotfan

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/251282/how-to-change-velocity-&-acceleration-in-motionplanrequest-topic/) by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on ROS Answers with karma: 10937 on 2017-01-04

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It depends on what interface you are using to make the planning request. If you are making the service call yourself, it is trivial to set the `max_velocity_scaling_factor` and  `max_acceleration_scaling_factor` manually.

When using the the move_group C++ API, you have a function for the [velocity](http://docs.ros.org/jade/api/moveit_ros_planning_interface/html/classmoveit_1_1planning__interface_1_1MoveGroup.html#a24f5ed1dad9e46d114c0c895b241ddc9) and for the [acceleration](http://docs.ros.org/jade/api/moveit_ros_planning_interface/html/classmoveit_1_1planning__interface_1_1MoveGroup.html#ac82f6937c4a43690bc9fef08c42cee7e). These updates factors will then be used for the next planning request.

the `moveit_commander` move_group interface also has these functions ([velocity](http://docs.ros.org/jade/api/moveit_commander/html/classmoveit__commander_1_1move__group_1_1MoveGroupCommander.html#a020b41d385657da906d746f97dcab4a6) and [acceleration](http://docs.ros.org/jade/api/moveit_commander/html/classmoveit__commander_1_1move__group_1_1MoveGroupCommander.html#afb7258005ff7c2447332840039a76403))

Setting the acceleration is quite recent for `moveit_commander` but I'm pretty sure it is in 0.7.6.

---

Originally posted by [rbbg](https://answers.ros.org/users/26757/rbbg/) with karma: 1823 on 2017-01-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2017-02-24**:
Thanks. `set_max_acceleration_scaling_factor` is still missing from Indigo, so I opened [a PR](https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit/pull/451) for it.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The **move_group** node advertises a "/plan_kinematic_path" service which takes in [moveit_msgs/GetMotionPlan](http://docs.ros.org/api/moveit_msgs/html/srv/GetMotionPlan.html) service request.  You just need to populate the request message with you plan details (including velocity and acceleration scaling) and call the service.  There are some useful [utility function](http://docs.ros.org/jade/api/moveit_core/html/namespacekinematic__constraints.html#a88becba14be9ced36fefc7980271e132)s that can be used to populate the **MotionPlanRequest.msg** fields.

---

Originally posted by [jrgnicho](https://answers.ros.org/users/22410/jrgnicho/) with karma: 486 on 2017-01-06

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2